# After device restart ,How to Get Dumpstate/ABD logs of old session

Tags: java, android, logging, adb

Folks,

Somehow i ended up here and want to know is there any hidden commands to get logs?"After device restart ,How to Get Dumpstate/ABD logs of old session."

Does android system writes some logs for debugging issues when it restarts randomly?

Thanks
NitZ

Answer (score 0):

As per your application state, you can save the logs in text file like this -

```
public void appendLog(String text)
{       
   File logFile = new File("sdcard/log.file");
   if (!logFile.exists())
   {
      try
      {
         logFile.createNewFile();
      } 
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   try
   {
      //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
      BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
      buf.append(text);
      buf.newLine();
      buf.close();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Hope this helps :)